# Nested AD security groups

Tags: active-directory

I hope this is the right discussion group.
Disclaimer: I'm, not a Windows/System admin but being a net-admin I have to deal with the Windows world

I'm trying to understand how to simplify my work in writing the NPS rules because MS NPS (Network Policy Server) checks if a user is in a Windows group (Security group afaik) but apparently only at the first level and doesn't go through the nested ones.

For those who don't know, say I have 17 OU with users in them. And there is a sec group for each OU, hence 17 Sec Groups.
Now there are 5 VPN/802.1x services (whose authentication is done by NPS) granted to some Sec groups but not to others.

To simplify I will provide a description of which group belongs is granted to which service:

Service1 is granted to Sec1,Sec5,Sec6,Sec7,Sec10

Service2 is granted to Sec2,Sec3,Sec6,Sec7,Sec11,Sec12,Sec14

Service3 is granted to Sec1,Sec5

Service4 is granted to Sec3,Sec4,Sec5,Sec11,Sec12,Sec13,Sec14,Sec15,Sec17

Service5 is granted to Sec1,Sec8,Sec9,Sec10,Sec17

I thought I could create 5 Sec parent groups like Secgrpserv1, Secgrpserv2, Secgrpserv3, Secgrpserv4, Secgrpserv5 in AD and then specify them in the NPS conditions of the Network Policy (instead of adding as many rules as the Sec Groups benefitting that service) because otherwise the NPS rules would explode and would be difficult to manage.

Is there a smart way (on the AD side I hope) to do this?

Thanks, Alex

**EDIT: the most pertinent discussion on the Internet I've found so far is this**

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/660754b5-5dcf-42e2-a1cc-e3524567bb35/nested-groups-in-windows-groups-condition?forum=winserverNIS

The parent group and the child members are all Global GRoups if this may help.

Comment: What version of Windows Server are you using?

Comment: Are you certain MS NPS server doesn't supported nested groups? I'm like 95% sure it does. It's been awhile since I set it up, but I heavily depend on nested groups so I feel like I would have noticed if it didn't support them.

Comment: @RobbieCrash 2012 R2

Comment: @Grant: this is what I noticed. Maybe I did a wrong setup but what I wrote in my post describes my setup. I will be glad to provide details if I'm told which ones (and possibly how)

Comment: 2008 had issues with nested groups, iirc, but in 2012 it's definitely supported. I just spun up a 2012R2 NPS and cannot replicate the behaviour.  Are you specifying multiple instances of the group membership condition in the network policy? If you are specifying Windows Groups multiple times in one policy they are treated as AND requirements, not OR requirements.

Comment: @RobbieCrash: indeed it was the mistake during the tetheting period of the implementation, then as netadmin I created as many subsequent rules as the Windows SecGroups, then by investigating a bit how Sec Groups work I asked sysadmin to create a SecGroups that baiscally mapped :1 with the Services but despite the fact that the super SecGroup was put on top of the other rules in the Network Plicies, still the rule hit was the one where the directly belonged SecGroup the user was in :-(